# How to check if period between two dates intersects with array of years

Tags: php, laravel, date, time

I have a Laravel project. My model has fields timestamps "start" and "end". The request has a parameter as array of years, etc:`years = [2019, 2021, ...]`.

I would like to get by `Model::where(...)`,  `Model::whereIn(...)` or something all records that intersect with the "years" parameter.

Example:

If `years = [2019, 2021]`, I need to get records with `start = "2018-01-01", end = "2019-12-31"` or `start = "2018-01-01", end = "2025-12-31"`, but **NOT**  `start = "2020-01-01", end = "2020-12-31"`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Better to use `Carbon`

Comment: What is logic behind taking 2018-01-01 for start_date?

Answer (score 0):

How about next solution:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

$years = [2019, 2021];

Model::where(
    static function (Builder $query) use ($years) {
        foreach ($years as $year) {
            $start = "{$year}-01-01";
            $end = "{$year}-12-31";
            $query->orWhereRaw("('{$start}' BETWEEN `start` AND '{$end}' OR `start` BETWEEN '{$start}' AND '{$end}')");
        }
    }
);
```

OR

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

$years = [2019, 2021];

Model::where(
    static function (Builder $query) use ($years) {
        foreach ($years as $year) {
            $query->orWhere(
                static function (Builder $query) use ($year) {
                    $query->whereYear('start', $year)
                        ->whereYear('end', $year);
                }
            );
        }
    }
);
```